# QA Validation between QlikSense Report data and DB data

Tags: validation, ui-automation, qliksense

I am the QA Analyst for a project where we have a data warehouse on a SQL Server database, with Qlik serving as the front end for report visualization.

Our primary goal from a QA perspective is to validate that the data displayed on Qlik reports is correct and consistent with the data stored in the SQL Server database tables.

Currently, we are able to perform this validation manually, but we are interested in automating the process to improve efficiency and reduce potential errors.

I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations on how to proceed with automating our QA validation.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I am expecting an advice or guidance to automate Data validation

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could achieve this in a few ways. One path to achieve this:

- In your SQL Server database, create views for each of the metrics or charts that you want to track in your Qlik app(s). Use a standardized naming convention for those views, like `MetricDef_AvgSalesByProductGroupAllYears` or similar.
- In Qlik, create Master Visualizations for the KPIs or charts that you want to track. When naming those Master Visualizations, use the same names for the matching SQL Server views you created. You could also use tags as long as they are under the character limit.
- Write a script using JavaScript, C#, or Go that will dynamically go through your app(s), search for all Master Visualizations that start with `MetricDef_` for example, and then check the result set against the SQL Server views in a row-to-row comparison.

  - An important note here is that Qlik KPIs and charts use the concept called a [HyperCube](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2023/Subsystems/Platform/Content/Sense_PlatformOverview/Concepts/Hypercubes.htm) to represent the underlying data. HyperCubes can be complex and messy, particularly if you use charts that have "stacked" or "pivoted" data like stacked bar charts or pivot tables, respectively. In order to compare your Qlik chart data with the corresponding SQL view data, they will need to be a comparable format, like JSON or similar.

Here's some sample JavaScript code that will get the HyperCubes for any Master Visualizations that have titles beginning with `MetricDef_` and then output them as JSON objects:

```
const q = await engineModuleGlobal.getCurrentApp();

const mis = await q.getObjects({
    "qOptions": {
        "qTypes": [
            "masterobject"
        ]
    }
});

const mis_array = mis.qList;

const mis_filtered = mis_array.filter(x => x.qMeta.tags.some(y => y.startsWith("MetricsDef_")));

mis_filtered.forEach(async m => {
    const o = await q.getObject(m.qInfo.qId);
    const l = await o.getLayout();

    const hc = await o.getHyperCubeData({
        "qPath": "/qHyperCubeDef", "qPages": [
            {
                "qTop": 0,
                "qLeft": 0,
                "qHeight": l.qHyperCube.qSize.qcy,
                "qWidth": l.qHyperCube.qSize.qcx
            }
        ]
    });

    const fields = [...l.qHyperCube.qDimensionInfo, ...l.qHyperCube.qMeasureInfo].map((f) => f.qFallbackTitle);

    const table = hc[0].qMatrix.map(row => {
        let o = {};
        row.forEach((cell, ix) => {
            o[fields[ix]] = cell.qText;
        });
        return o;
    });

    console.log(table);
});
```

That code skips the steps involved with getting [Enigma.js](https://qlik.dev/toolkits/enigma-js/) set up, but it's not too complicated. It also is only written to handle "straight" HyperCubes, so additional code would need to be written to handle other types (see the **qMode** property in the table in [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2023/Subsystems/EngineJSONAPI/Content/models-hypercubedef.htm)). And if you end up going down the JavaScript route, you could use the popular [mssql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to connect to your SQL Server databases and run those view queries.